# Access "bundleIdentifier" value from ./src-tauri/tauri.conf.json in app?

Tags: json, tauri

The Tauri project file `./src-tauri/tauri.conf.json` has the JSON value `tauri.bundle.identifier: "com.tauri.dev"`.

How do I access it from within my app?

---

### My Usecase

I need to write to `${dataDir}/${bundleIdentifier}/my-file.txt`. Like so:

```
const fs = window.__TAURI__.fs;
const path = window.__TAURI__.path;
const id = "com.tauri.dev";

let filename = "my-file.txt";
let _path = await path.join(id, filename);

let data = "Hello World!";

await fs.writeFile({
    path: _path,
    contents: data
}, { dir: fs.Dir.Data });
```

Except I want to get the `com.tauri.dev` value from from `./src-tauri/tauri.conf.json` rather than being manually inserted.

What's the proper way to do that?

Comment: Aside from the answer below you can also simply use appDataDir which is dataDir with the bundleid appended already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the simples Rust way to do it would be to just include it in your binary like so:

(not tested code)

```rust
let config_json = include_str!("../tauri.conf.json");
// then you parse json
let v: Value = serde_json::from_str(config_json)?
let id = v["tauri"]["bundle"]["identifier"];
println!("{id}")
```

The proper Tauri way is to get App's handle and access [config](https://docs.rs/tauri/latest/tauri/struct.App.html#method.config) directly.

```rust
tauri::Builder::default()
  .setup(|app| {
    let app_handle = app.handle();
    let config = app_handle.config.lock(); // <-- this is tauri config
    Ok(())
  });
```

One more version:

```rust
fn main() {
  let context = tauri::generate_context!();
  let tauri_bundle_identifier = context.config().tauri.bundle.identifier;

  println!("{tauri_bundle_identifier}");
  
  tauri::Builder::default()
    .context(context)
    //...... setup, etc
    .run("error running tauri app");
}
```